# Can I convert a pointer to my class?

Tags: c++, casting, implicit-conversion

I'm refactoring a class for my project to adapt int data. The code is quite complicated, try to give a simple example below:

```
struct A {
  A(int a):a_(a) {}  // Supports implicit conversion from int
  int a_;
};

void print(A a) { cout<<a.a_<<endl; }

void x2(A *a) {   // change a's value
  a->a_ *= 2;
}

int main() {
  int b = 2;
  print(b);      // pass int as A without any problem
  x2(&b);        // pass int* as A* - failed
  cout<<b<<endl; // b is supposed to changed by x2()
}
```

In this case maybe template is a good choice, but I'm afraid rewritting the whole class with template would be a huge effort and would do a little harm to the readablity especially for my colleagues.

Is there any other way to use "int*" as "A*"?

Comment: I think treating `int*` as a `A*` would do much more harm, both to readibility and correctness of your code, than templates. If you really want you can do `A a(42); x2(&a);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no "way". What you are trying to do here is violating the contract on `x2`, which is that `a` will be a valid pointer to `A`.

The simplest change to it would be to change `x2` to:
(There's really no need to use a pointer here)

```
void x2 (A& a) {
    a.a_ *= 2;
}
```

And then call it with A value that's wrapped around the int (like @jrok suggested):

```
A a(2);
x2(a);
```

If you are conderned with printing, provide `operator<<` for A.

Comment: After changing x2 as void x2(A& a), you can also add references to your struct ctor and member. That way, you can call x2 as:
{ int b = 12;
x2(A(b)); }  Just creating the object when needed.

Comment: @jujujuijk last time I've checked rvalue won't work in place of non-const lvalue.